# Remove Duplicate and Wrong termination date

Tags: sql, ssms

I need to caculate the year differences for years of services of employee. Some employees have multiple job records (terminated and rehire situation). I was able to identify it by distinct last hire date, but previous last hire dates are followed by one real termination date and one wrong termination date of '1900-01-1'. '1900-01-1' represent the current date if the employee is active which is only right for the latest last_hire_dt. How can I remove all the '1900-01-1' in previous last hire datas?

I attached a sample employee table and code I have right now below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqRLm.png)

My current code:

```sql
SELECT distinct PERSON_ID, LAST_HIRE_DT, TERMINATION_DT,
       (CASE 
             WHEN Termination_dt = '1900-01-01' 
               THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Last_Hire_dt, GETDATE()) 
             ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, Last_Hire_dt, Termination_dt) 
           END) / 365.25 AS total_years_of_service 
FROM EMPLOYEE_JOB
where PERSON_ID = '10000669'
order by  LAST_HIRE_DT desc
```

I'm thinking if I can order desc by total_years_of_service and truncate the top (n-1)/2 rows for all employee who has more than 2 rows will remove the wrong data. But, it is a complicate way. It will be better to write a query to not include all previous duplicated last hire date that have termination date of '1900-01-01'.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Will you always pass one `PERSON_ID` at a time to return the data you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First CTE (LastDate) gets the last hire date per employee. We need this if the employee still works there.

Second CTE (CorrectedTermDt) removes the rows with 1/1/1900 termination dates. If the employee still works there, it keeps the row with the MaxHireDt and replaces 1/1/1900 with NULL.

The final select calculates the years of service.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xppZcgPU)

```
WITH LastDate AS
  (SELECT PersonID
        , MAX(LastHireDt) MaxHireDt
     FROM Employee
 GROUP BY PersonID
  )
  , CorrectedTermDt AS
  (SELECT em.PersonID
        , em.LastHireDt
        , CASE WHEN em.TerminationDt = '1/1/1900' THEN NULL ELSE em.TerminationDt END AS TerminationDt
     FROM Employee em
LEFT JOIN LastDate ld ON ld.PersonID = em.PersonId
 WHERE em.TerminationDt <> '1/1/1900'
    OR em.LastHireDt = ld.MaxHireDt
  )
SELECT PersonID
     , LastHireDt
     , TerminationDt
     , CASE WHEN TerminationDt IS NULL
                 THEN DATEDIFF(Day, LastHireDt, GETDATE())/ 365.25
                 ELSE DATEDIFF(Day, LastHireDt, TerminationDt)/ 365.25
        END AS [TotalService (Years)]
  FROM CorrectedTermDt
```

| PersonID | LastHireDt | TerminationDt | TotalService (Years) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000669 | 2021-09-20 | null | 1.544147 |
| 10000669 | 2018-09-23 | 2021-09-18 | 2.986995 |
| 10000669 | 2009-03-15 | 2009-11-16 | 0.673511 |
| 10000669 | 2006-06-04 | 2008-10-12 | 2.357289 |

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This does solve my question in a more efficient way!